# How to spy a class who has an Annotation with Mockito?

Tags: java, junit, tdd

I want to spy a class who has a custom Annotation, but when I try to get annotations it has not anything.

My class is defined as:

```
@FisaEntity(name="TCRB_AFL_AFFILIATION", applicationId="CRB_AFL_REQ", master=true)
@PrimaryKeyFields(names={"CRB-TCRB_AFL_AFFILIATION-AFFILIATION_ID", "CRB-TCRB_AFL_AFFILIATION-AFFIL_SEQ" })
public class Affiliation{

}
```

When I try to get the annotations with this code:

```
FisaEntity entityAnnotation = (FisaEntity)klass.getAnnotation(FisaEntity.class);
```

And my test run this:

```
Affiliation affiliation = spy(new Affiliation());
```

Debugging my code, I can see my variable klass is:

```
com.req.model.Affiliation$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$123@123
```

Do anyone know any hack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You answered your question yourself:

```
com.req.model.Affiliation$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$123@123
```

Simply don't make any assumption on mocks or spies. Use them for what they are meant to be: "test stubs" that provide **functionality** (aka behavior) to you.

In other words: you create mocks so that you can control/verify method calls made on these objects. You somehow inject the mocks into your code under test to get to the effects you intend to cause/observe.

Anything beyond that, like "hoping" that the class created by Mockito to do its magic has all the same annotations and whatnot of the original class: simply not a good approach.

As said: you are mocking objects to control their behavior, not the **structural composition** of the corresponding class that Mockito has to generate in order to instantiate the mocked objects.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I notice a design problem with this question I think it needs a refactor.

Answer (score 1):

```
Class clazz = Affiliation.class;
Annotation[] annotations = clazz.getAnnotations();
Annotation annotation = clazz.getAnnotation(Component.class);
```

These both should give you all the annotations of the class and the particular annotation of the class.

From your question, it is not clear what `klass` is!

If the purpose of your testing is solely to test that the annotation exists, then this way you can get the annotation(s) and then assert them...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the variable klass is composed by Mockito, and the annotations disappear when I try to get the annotations with the methods of class clazz.getAnnotations() returns null.